# Customer order attribute not saving on one server

Tags: attributes, orders

So, I have a checkout module which has a boolean custom order attribute which is defined like this (attribute name replaced):

```
<?php

$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/setup', 'sales_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    'order',
    'success_accessed',
    array(
        'type' => 'boolean',
        'required' => 0,
        'comment' => "success view has been accessed"
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

And in a controller (`IndexController`) it is handled as follows:

```
if ($order->getSuccessAccessed()) {
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    return;
} else {
    $order->setSuccessAccessed(true);
    $order->save();
}
```

Now, when testing this on two different dev servers and one other production server this works as intended. After the first time a user accesses the success view they get redirected to the cart if they attempt to access the success view again (the reason for why we need this logic is long-winded and involves peculiarities of the payment processing API that this checkout module is tied to so alternative solutions would most likely involve rewriting and restructuring not just our own code but also a 3rd party API, just sayin').

However, on this particular production server I'm dealing with right now the above code in the controller does absolutely nothing. The attribute value isn't set nor is `updated_at` on the order being changed.

There are no errors in any log files and putting log statements before and after every line (no xdebug on production servers) shows that execution is not halted anywhere and code that runs after these lines is also getting executed.

Does anyone have any clues what might be causing this one server to ignore the `$order->save();` call?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer to the problem. After trying a complete reindex and flushing the cache I decided to just straight up try restarting apache. And apparently this worked (what's odd is that the log statements I put into the code took effect immediately?)